# How to get from $a\sqrt{1 + \frac{b^2}{a^2}}$ to $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following expression: $a\sqrt{1 + \frac{b^2}{a^2}}$.  If I plug this into Wolfram Alpha, it tells me that, if $a, b$ are positive, this equals $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

How do I get that result?  I can't see how that could be done.  Thanks

Comment: Hint:  for positive $a$, $a = \sqrt{a^2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a\ge0$,
$$\begin{align}
a\sqrt{1 + \frac{b^2}{a^2}}
&=\sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{1 + \frac{b^2}{a^2}}
\\
&=\sqrt{a^2\left(1 + \frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)}
\\
&=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}.
\end{align}$$

($\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|a|=a$ when $a\ge0$.)

Answer (score 5):

$$a\sqrt{1 + \frac{b^2}{a^2}}$$

$$=a\sqrt{\frac{a^2 + b^2}{a^2}}$$

$$=a\frac{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{|a|}$$

So when $a$ and $b$ are positive, $|a|=a$. Hence:

$$=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$

Without the assumption:

$$\sqrt{a^2} =|a|=\begin{cases}   a   && a \geq 0\\   -a &&a < 0\\   \end{cases}$$